# Replacing double quotes with space, Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, str-replace

I am trying to replace/remove all instances of double quotes specified in a string in Google Apps Script but am unsuccessful in doing this.

I have tried the following:

```
str.replace(/["']/g,"");
```

but this does not work in Google Apps Script, works in JavaScript.

Can you please advise if this is possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you found an answer to this question?

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
str = str.replace(/\"+/g,"");
```